# Error code when trying to localize application with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I'm beginning learning Internalization in Rails and was trying to test my locale Brazilian Portugese file in the console and I got this error message

```
#<Psych::SyntaxError: (/home/adamgraham/Desktop/Rails/blog/config/locales/pt-br.yml): did not find expected node content while parsing a flow node at line 74 column 11>
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:184:in `rescue in load_yml'
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:181:in `load_yml'
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:165:in `load_file'
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `block in load_translations'
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `load_translations'
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:57:in `init_translations'
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:40:in `available_locales'
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/config.rb:43:in `available_locales'
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n/config.rb:49:in `available_locales_set'
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:278:in `locale_available?'
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:284:in `enforce_available_locales!'
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/i18n-0.7.0/lib/i18n.rb:151:in `translate'
from (irb):6
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:69:in `console'
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
from /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
```

This is my pt-br.yml file

```
pt-br:
  general:
    title: Blog
    title_field: titulo
    categories: Categorias 
    excerpt: Excerto
    body: Corpo
    published_at: Publicada na
    location: Localizacao
    cancel: Cancelar
    or: ou
    footer: Um blog simples desenvolvido para o livro
    title: Blog
    email_friend: Avisar um amigo
    send_email: Mandar email
    your_friends_email: O email do seu amigo
    your_name: Seu nome
    show: Mostrar
    back: Volta
    edit: Editar
    delete: Apagar
    are_you_sure: Tem certeza?
  application:
    access_denied: :Por favor, efetue o login para continuar
  articles:
    new_article: Novo artigo
    listing_articles: Listando Artigo
    editing_articles: Editando Artigo
    create_success: Artigo foi atualizado com successo
    create_not_success: não é bem sucedida
  users:
    edit_password: Editar senha
    new_user: Novo Usuario
    create_success: Usuario editado com sucesso
    update_success: Usuario atualizado com sucesso
  sessions:
    password: senha
    email: Email
    login: Logar
    logout: Desconectar
    destroy_success: Voce desconector do sistem com sucesso
    create_not_success: Senha ou Email invalidos
    create_success: Logado com sucesso
  comments:
    new_comment: Novo Comentario
    comments: Comentarios
    destroy_success: Comentario deletado 
    create_not_success: Nao foi possivel adicionar o comentario
    create_success: Obrigado pelo comentario
  errors:
    not_published_yet: ainda nao foi publicado
    prohibited_from_saving: proibido de poupança

  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        article:
          attributes:
            title:
              blank: "nao pode ficar em branco"
            body:
              blank: "nao pode ficar em branco"

date:
  format:
    default: "%d/%m/%Y"
    short: "d de %B"
    long: "%d de %B de %Y"

  day_names: [Domingo, Segunda, Terca, Quarta, Quinta, Sexta, Sabado]
  abbr_day_names: [Dom, Seg, Ter, Qua, Qui, Sex, Sab]
  month_names: [~, Janeiro, Fevereiro, Marco, Abril, Maio, Junho, Julho, Agosto, Setembro, Outubro, Novembro, Dezembro]
  abbr_month_names: [~, Jan, Fev, Mar, Abr, Mai, Jun, Jul, Ao, Set, Out, Nov, Dez]
  order: [:day, :month, :year]
```

This is the application.html.erb file layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Blog</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    <h1><%= link_to t('general.title'), root_path %></h1>
    <div id="user_bar">
      <% if logged_in? %>
        <%= link_to t('articles.new_article'), new_article_path %> |
        <%= link_to t('users.edit_password') ,     edit_user_path(current_user) %> |
        <%= link_to t('sessions.logout'), logout_path %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to t('sessions.login'), login_path %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <%= content_tag(:p, notice, :class => 'notice') if notice.present? %>
    <%= content_tag(:p, alert, :class => 'alert') if alert.present? %>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
   <div id="footer">
    t('general.footer') <a href="http://beginningrails.com">Beginning Rails 3</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am running Rails 4.1.10, Ruby 2.1.5
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not post the top line of the error?! Our edit so it's visible? What line and column is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BR should be capitalized in your root node and in the filename. See: an example here https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/pt-BR.yml

Comment: Never mind I got it to work once I changed it to capital BR